# Is there really a NumericUpDown Text property?

Tags: vb.net, numericupdown

I was looking at the class for NumericUpDown on MSDN and I saw "Text" in the properties list. Does this exist? I tried using it in VS 2010, but it did not work. I used .Value instead, but I would like .Text better.

Comment: It is hidden.  If you want to up/down text then you should be using a DomainUpDown.  NumericUpDown is strictly for numbers.